# Is it possible to restore only permissions from a SharePoint 2010 backup?

Tags: 2010, permissions, backup, restore

Is there a way to only restore permissions and not the content from a SharePoint 2010 back-up?

If yes, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Saumil,

that is not possible. What you coud do:
* restore the content database to another sitecollection
* synchronize the permissions between the two sitecollections with some custom written powershell. I don't think there's an easier way.

Answer (score 1):

You can with some 3rd party tools like Quest Security Explorer.  Essentially you would take a backup of the security, and then when needed you could restore it.

**http://www.quest.com/security-explorer/**